# Odoo what method is used automatically fill many2many relation table values on select button

Tags: python-2.7, orm, odoo, odoo-9

I have 2 classes:

```
class my_request(models.Model):

    _name = 'my.request'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

    supply_ids  = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='supply.conditions',
                                              relation='purchase_supply_rel',
                                              column1='purchase_requests_id', column2='supply_conditions_id',
                                              string='Supply Conditions')
```

and

```
class SupplyConditions(models.Model):
    _name = 'supply.conditions'
```

piece of xml:

```
<page string="Order">
      <field name="supply_ids" domain="[('purchase_id', '=', id)]"/>
</page>
```

When I open a list of values:

[image]

And click on **Select** button and then **Save button** relational table is updated: 
purchase_requests_id and supply_conditions_id values are inserted in **purchase_supply_rel** table automatically.

My problem is that **on Save button click** I need to do more (call function which fill other table with specific values). As I understand I need to know what method is used on this `Save button click` and I need to expand it yes?

Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the initial context. If you're creating a new record of `my.request` it will call the `create()` ORM method. If you're updating a record it will call `write()` ORM method instead. So you will have to extend both.

Comment: On Save button click I am creating new many2many record in relational table (purchase_supply_rel). When I am creating a new record of my.request I click on Create button. Do these buttons call the same create() method? How can I separate if new record is creating inmy_request table or in purchase_supply_rel many2many relational table? Thank you in advance

Comment: No, many2manny relations are created within `create()` or `write()` (for further information look [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/fields.py#L2355)). On creating a new record and relating it directly (Button Create in many2many list widget), it should call the `create()` of the model you're creating there, in your example it should be `supply.conditions`.

Comment: Thank you. So when I click on Save button as I understand of my.request model is called write() method which call create() method of my supply.conditions model. So I have to overwrite create() method of supply.conditions model? BTW I am using 9 Odoo version.

Comment: Correct. Just override these methods an debug into them, to understand it a bit more :-)

Comment: I'll try. Thanks!